# Discord Integer delete mention <@Deleted-Role>

Tags: discord.py, integer, embed

I'm wondering if any of you guys can figure out how i could use my role : Name : Color Magenta. Id. 855179067388461076

Known Issue: Discord have limitation of integer maximum lenght. I believe.. that's what i know..

```
 @bot.command()
async def Shop(ctx):
    roleId = "855179067388461076>"
    ShopEM = discord.Embed(title=f" BASIC COLORS SHOP ", color=0xff5555)
    ShopEM.add_field(name=f"1) Magenta", value=f'<@&' + (roleId), inline=True)
    ShopEM.add_field(name=f"2) khaki ", value=f"<@&1075540590604853278>", inline=False)
    ShopEM.add_field(name=f"3) Purple",  value=f"<@&1075540578072273006>", inline=False)
    ShopEM.add_field(name=f"4) Gray", value=f"<@&1075540541195960400>", inline=True)
    ShopEM.add_field(name=f"5) Olive ", value=f"@&1075540533457461379>", inline=False)
    ShopEM.add_field(name=f"6) Teal", value=f"<@&1075540547021840404>", inline=False)
    ShopEM.add_field(name=f"PRICE", value="")
    await ctx.send(embed=ShopEM)
```

Output : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure:

- that the bot has permissions to mention those roles?
- that those IDs are the correct roles for this server?

My code below, very similar to yours, works absolutely fine. I only got `deleted-role` when I entered in numbers that were made up or for roles not in this server.

```py
@bot.command()
async def shop(ctx):
    # list of tuples to iterate over with the role name and then role ID
    roles = [
        ("bots", "1065670055507005128"),
        ("server booster", "1068466410612867541"),
        ("human", 1064550904461795018),
        ("admin", 813738863871787428)

    ]
    shop_em = discord.Embed(title=" BASIC COLORS SHOP ", color=0xff5555)
    
    # iterate over the roles and add them to the embed
    for role in roles:
        shop_em.add_field(name=role[0], value=f"<@&{role[1]}>", inline=True)

    await ctx.send(embed=shop_em)
```

**Note**: Putting the IDs as ints or strings didn't matter at all. For example, I use both here and there weren't issues with either.

Example of it working:

[image: example role shop]

Comment: Yep, i tried, i verified. Same issue. Even when i try to put it manually, in discord, I got "Deleted role"

Comment: Worked after i reinstalled the VPS by all, somehow this was the problem, after i reinstaled every library, in my ubuntu server. and copy pasted the bot once again, worked.